# Merging in git after changing file name capitalization

Tags: git, merge

So I changed all the file names in my repo from upper case to lower case. If I tried to do it the standard way I would get the following error.

```
$ git mv Actuals.py actuals.py
fatal: destination exists, source=Actuals.py, destination=actuals.py
```

So i used the `force` option

```
$ git mv -f Actuals.py actuals.py
warning: destination exists; will overwrite!
```

It worked but now when I try and checkout another branch I run into trouble.

```
$ git checkout integration
error: Untracked working tree file 'Actuals.py' would be overwritten by merge.
```

So I force that too:

```
$ git checkout -f integration
Switched to branch 'integration'
```

But now I'm really in trouble because when I try to merge the previous branch into this one, I get blocked again:

```
$ git merge develop
Updating 6256d82..a5b3ea1
error: Untracked working tree file 'actuals.py' would be overwritten by merge.  Aborting
```

Short of creating local copies of these files and deleting and adding every one on every branch I want to merge to, how do I do this?

Comment: Why would you use `git mv` instead of `mv`?

Comment: @intboolstring because then the repo would not detect the changes, and other users would check out the names with the wrong case. The syntax in the files would then fail.

Comment: what version of git on what platform?

Comment: @TriskalJM it is 1.7.1 on CentOS 6.6

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work around (though I don't think it needs to be this involved). I changed the name of each file in the original branch to a modified name and committed the changes:

```
$ git mv actuals.py _actuals.py
```

for each file, then I checkout the other branch and merge it in. All of the files now have the new names. I then checkout the original branch and rename everything back to the intended name:

```
$ git mv _actuals.py actuals.py
```

Commit everything, checkout the second branch and remerge. Now all the files are correct. This method allows for typos unless you build a script so I'm not exactly a fan but it let me merge my branches.